# What mnemonic device or rhyme /reason is there for g/G/h/H in php's date() syntax?

Tags: php, date, time

I've been using PHP for a while now - but when I need to use `date()` to format a time, I can never remember the hour syntax correctly. Is there any trick for remembering the rhyme and reason for using g/G/h/H ?

From the PHP manual for `date()` :

```
g   | 12-hour format of an hour without leading zeros   | 1 through 12
G   | 24-hour format of an hour without leading zeros   | 0 through 23
h   | 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros      | 01 through 12
H   | 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros      | 00 through 23
```

and in image format:

[php-time.png http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/5338/phptime.png](http://img593.imageshack.us/img593/5338/phptime.png)

Comment: It's PHP, there's no rhyme or reason.

Comment: copy and paste from the last time you used it. Get it tattooed on your arm (good for attracting the biker chicks)

Comment: I never try to remember such thing, I remember some of offen used format naturally, for the ones not offen used, I just check the manual when needed.

Comment: there's only so many letters you can use, and the more popular/frequently used ones were already used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea what the actual *reason* is, but ...

`h` or `H` is obviously hours. The capital letter is bigger, so it uses a bigger number of hours (24 vs. 12).

`g` or `G` is `h` or `H` without the leading `0`. `g` immediately precedes `h` in the alphabet.

You're going to want the leading `0` more often than not (because it aligns better), so that format gets the `h` for hours.

If that works for you, great. If not, consider writing the table on a [Post-it® Note](http://www.post-it.com/) and sticking it to your monitor.

Comment: @Dagon: No -- are they hiring?

Comment: "sticky php programmer wanted", oh wait that's another company :-)

Comment: actully yes: http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/careers/home/jobs/search/?jobfield=13860451504&location=-1&keyword=&jobNumberSearch=